# Encountering Error "Encountered Unknown Ink! attribute argument: path" in Ink! Smart Contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I am working on an Ink! smart contract in Rust, and I've encountered an error that I'm having trouble resolving. I followed a solution from a source [provide link here if applicable], but the problem persists.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

#[ink(path = "event.rs")]
mod event;

When I compile this code, I receive the following error message:

```
error: encountered unknown ink! attribute argument: path
```

I've tried searching for information and solutions online, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer. Can someone please help me understand what this error means and how I can resolve it?

I'm using Rust version 1.72 and Ink! version 4.0 , and any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

I was using example code from this link - [Support multi-file ink! projects](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/259)